# Javascript ORM Library

Tags: javascript, database, orm, web-sql

I am currently working on an application that stores all the data locally on the device,
and updates it whenever there is a change.

Therefore, I am looking for a way to store, read and update objects **with relations between them** inside client-side javascript code easily.

I know I can use localStorage, WebSQL, IndexedDB or plain Javascript Object,
but I am looking for ORM or something that will simplify the actions and handle the relations for me.

I am aware of the [JayData](http://jaydata.org/) library but looking for better alternatives.

Comment: I'm very interested in this too. Particularly one that is not interdependent with another library like jquery etc. or makes unnecessary assumptions about the environment (like the existence of a DOM). I couldn't find anything, so I'm building my own which I'd be happy to open source, but it's really not far enough along yet for that.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a Database in your Browser maybe [PuchDB](http://pouchdb.com/) is what you need.

You can find the API-documentation here: http://pouchdb.com/api.html. Everything can be stored at localStorage of the clients WebBrowser.

Example:

```
var db = new PouchDB('dbname');

// save some data
db.put({
  _id: 'mydoc',
  title: 'Heroes'
}, function(err, response) { });

// get som
db.get('mydoc', function(err, doc) { });
```

I hope this was helpfull :-)

Answer (score 1):

Have you checkout my own library, ydn-db. It does not handle relationship, but otherwise very good [non-relational ORM](http://dev.yathit.com/ydn-db/schema.html) ;-).